# struts2 ognl expression

Tags: struts2

In my JSP I have:

```
<s:textarea name="${param.objId}"/>
```

This renders the following:

```
<textarea name="categoryObject.linkAttrValue[#ddAttr.id].link.id" 
   cols="" rows=""
   id="browseCategoryObject_categoryObject_linkAttrValue_#ddAttr_id__link_id">7</textarea>
```

Similarly, I have a property tag:

```
<s:property value="${param.objId}"/>
```

which renders:

```
7
```

Finally, a submit tag:

```
<s:submit action="addRepeatingCategoryObject" value="addNew"
   onclick="$('input[name=ddRepeatingAttrId]').val(%{#${param.objId}}); alert(%{#${param.objId}});   $('input[name=ddRepeatingAttrId]').val(%{#${param.innerDdAttr}.id}); " />
```

that renders:

```
<input type="submit" id="browseCategoryObject_addRepeatingCategoryObject"
       name="action:addRepeatingCategoryObject" value="addNew"  
       onclick="$('input[name=ddRepeatingAttrId]').val(); alert();   $('input[name=ddRepeatingAttrId]').val(4); "/>
```

Expression `%{#${param.innerDdAttr}.id}` is resolved in `s:submit`, but `%{#${param.objId}}` is not resolved in `s:submit` but is resolved in `s:property` and  `s:textarea`.

Does anybody have idea why it works in this way?

---

I tried `%{${param.objId}}` instead of `%{#${param.objId}}` and it worked.

But I can't explain why it works...

Comment: Is that really your onclick handler? Please consider moving it out of the tag--that's impossible to read.

Comment: Hi, don't you think it could be jquery conflict? if you need some remote content in your jquery function, i can try <s:property value=""/> instead of ${}

Comment: @Jaiwo99 No; JSP EL is evaluated on the server side.

Comment: You need to include what Struts 2 version you're using; JSP EL has been explicitly disallowed in OGNL expressions for some time due to the security risk. In any case, your code doesn't match what you last paragraph says, so IMO you should re-word the question.

Comment: I edit struts tld to enable JSP EL in OGNL

Answer (score 0):

Without having checked it, I think the following explanation should help:

Considering that in OGNL `%{}` escapes an OGNL expression, the following applies:

In OGNL, you have an expression `#beanName` or `${beanName}` to get the value of the bean `beanName` from the root context.  If you do the following: `#${beanName}`, you will actually look up the name of the bean first and then use that string to look up a value in the OGNL root context.

So, for `#${param.innerDdAttr}.id`, the following happens:

- Look up `param` in the OGNL contexts
- Get the value of the `innerDdAttr` property (which presumably will give you a value of "ddRepeatingAttrId")
- This means that `#${param.innerDdAttr}.id` will resolve to `#ddRepeatingAttrId.id`, so then
- Look up `ddRepeatingAttrId` in the OGNL context
- Get the value of the `id` property (which gives you the value of "4").

In contrast, for `#${param.objId}` what happens is:

- Look up `param` in the OGNL contexts
- Get the value of the `objId` property (which presumably will  you a value "7")
- This means that `#${param.innerDdAttr}.id` will resolve to `#7`, so then
- Look up `7` in the OGNL context, which doesn't find anything, so it doesn't print anything.

IMHO, instead of `%{#${param.objId}}`, you probably want `%{#param.objId}` or just `%{param.objId}` (difference is that with `#` it will only consider the root context, otherwise search the OGNL context).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your note.But ${param.objId} is resolved as  categoryObject.linkAttrValue[#ddAttr.id].link.id not as 7(it generated by simple ${param.objId} jsp text). I passed objId as param in jsp:include.

Comment: Fair point, but I still think that the issue is most likely to do with using `#${...}`.